# How can I get the current time of my host PC from Linux virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, python, date-time

I have a Kali-Linux virtual machine installed on my windows 10 PC (using oracle VM VirtualBox)
According to my timezone, the time is

```
11:26
```

I came across this problem:
When I used `datetime.datetime.now()` on my VM, I got the time

```
4:26
```

and then I realized that the time in the virtual machine is different from the host PC.
I was wondering if it's possible to get the time of the host machine in a script on the VM? without changing the settings of the VM? or installing something on (that is not a package from PyPi) the VM?

Comment: Install the guest extensions in your virtual machine and that should correct the time.

Comment: You might also check the timezone setting on the VM.